# Passed check on if not null is still assigning as null

Tags: c#

I have created a matching method which basically takes in a `Person` object, makes a call to an address service and then tries to do a match firstly by trying like for like and then if that does not work it concatenates the house name/number with the `saon` information (flat 1a etc) to see if that works.

If it does find a match I need to store that matched address in my variable `matchingAddress` and then process that further which is what the rest of the method does, I have excluded this for clarity.

**Problem**

I think I have a problem with my `lamda` statement, on the second `IF` with the person I am debugging with the if statement is returning true and I am dropping into the assignment code however it is being set to null even though the `IF` statement is meant to be checking that it is not `null`.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

```
private void AttemptMatch(Person person, string username)
        {
            var postcode = person.Postcode;

            List<JsonAddressModel> Addresses = _service.GetAddress(postcode); //returns a list of addresses for that persons postcode
            JsonAddressModel matchingAddress = new JsonAddressModel();

            //1.) Access the Service and see if theres a straight forward match
            if (Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.paon.Trim() == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo) != null)
            {
                matchingAddress = Addresses.First(x => x.paon.Trim() == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo);                
            }

            //2.) try and combine the paon and saon and see if that matches address line one            

            if (Addresses.Where(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.paon.Trim(), x.saon.Trim()) == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo) != null)
            {
                matchingAddress = Addresses.Where(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.paon.Trim(), x.saon.Trim()) == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            if (matchingAddress != null)
            {
                //rest of method to complete matching process for matched person         
            }

            else
                return;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop repeating work you've already done<sup>1</sup>, and just remove some of this conditional logic:

```
//1.) Access the Service and see if theres a straight forward match
//if (Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.paon.Trim() == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo) != null)
//{
matchingAddress = Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.paon.Trim() == person.AddressLineOne &&
                x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo) ??                
//}

//2.) try and combine the paon and saon and see if that matches address line one            

//if (Addresses.Where(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.paon.Trim(), x.saon.Trim()) == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo) != null)
//{
   /*matchingAddress = */
 Addresses.Where(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.paon.Trim(), x.saon.Trim()) ==
              person.AddressLineOne &&
              x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo).FirstOrDefault();              
//}
```

Your current problem is caused because in the second `if`, you're not calling any selection method (like `FirstOrDefault` or `ToList`, etc) and so what you're checking is whether the *query* is null rather than any result.

---

<sup>1</sup>At the moment, you run a query merely to determine whether it returns any results, and then you run the query *again* to actually obtain those results. Then, you potentially (if you'd not got the second `if` slightly wrong) do that same trick a second time, *and* use that to overwrite the previous result to boot, which was the actual result you wanted, I believe. So, instead, we just run one query, and if it returns null, we use `??` to move along and try the second query.

Comment: Should I be saying List.Where or List.FirstOrDefault ?

Comment: A `Where` followed by a `FirstOrDefault` can always (I think) be combined into just a `FirstOrDefault` call - easily (as here) if the `FirstOrDefault` call doesn't have its own lambda (just remove the `Where` and put its lambda in the `FirstOrDefault`) or with more effort if the two lambdas have to be combined. Some tools (such as Resharper) will even warn you if you write `Where(<something>).FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Resharper will answer that for you ;). It suggest that simplification everytime you chain a Where and a First[OrDefault] or Single[OrDefault]

Answer (score 1):

The reason you enter the `if` is that you are not calling `FirstOrDefault()` inside the condition. What's compared to `null` is the return of the `Where` method, which is never `null`.

You can optimize your code by storing the result of `FirstOrDefault` in a temporary variable, and then assigning it only when it's not `null`:

```
var tmp1 = Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.paon.Trim() == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo);
if (tmp1 != null) {
    matchingAddress = tmp1;                
}
var tmp2 = Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.paon.Trim(), x.saon.Trim()) == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo);
if (tmp2 != null) {
    matchingAddress = tmp2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
Addresses.Where(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.paon.Trim(), x.saon.Trim()) == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo) != null
```

For

```
Addresses.Any(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.paon.Trim(), x.saon.Trim()) == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo) != null
```

And ideally you won't need that if. Your SingleOrDefault should be doing the trick.

Basically the Where never returns null, it just return an empty IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

never returns null value. You need to check if returned collection is empty.

I suppose the best option is to change "where" with "any"

```
if (Addresses.Any(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.paon.Trim(), x.saon.Trim()) == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo))
```

Answer (score 0):

This linq is returning collection, which is always not null. It can be empty but never null.

Try this:

```
if (Addresses.Any(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.paon.Trim(), x.saon.Trim()) == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo))
{
matchingAddress = Addresses.Where(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.paon.Trim(), x.saon.Trim()) == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

It will check if there is any matching item.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your second if：

> ```
>         if (Addresses.Where(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.paon.Trim(), x.saon.Trim()) == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo).FirstOrDefault() != null)
>         {
>             matchingAddress = Addresses.Where(x => String.Format("{0} {1}", x.paon.Trim(), x.saon.Trim()) == person.AddressLineOne && x.thorofare.Trim() == person.AddressLineTwo).FirstOrDefault();
>         }
> ```

The 'Addresses.Where(filter)' return null is impossible. when all element in `IEnumerable<T>` not satisfied the where filter,  It would be return empty `IEnumerable<T>`